# Laplace smooth with trigrams

Tags: nlp

I have a trigram model with Laplace smoothing ,
my training sentence is     `A cat sat on the mat. A fat cat sat on the mat. A rat sat on the mat. The rat sat on the cat. A bat spat on the rat that sat on the cat on the mat.`

I want to evaluate the test sentence `a cat sat on the mat` (evaluation means calculating the likelihood).
the answer Is log(likelihood) = -4.297.(the answer is from my prof).
the problem is i cant figure out the calculation.
what I have tried is this : 
`log(p(a))+log(cat|a)+log(sat|a cat)+log(on|cat sat)+log(the|sat on)+log(mat|on the)=
-1.0492   + -0.9030  +  -0.8129     +   -0.845      +   -0.452      + -0.5797`
can some one help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How did you calculate `log(p(a))` and `log(p(cat|a))`??

Comment: p(a) = count(a)/N where N is the number of words, p(cat|a) = count(a cat)/count(a)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Markov approximation of the bigram model. In a trigram language model, we are dealing with triplets of tokens not pairs. In other words, the probability of `a cat sat on the mat` should be:

```
log(P(a cat sat on the mat)) =
   log(P(a|<s>, <s>)) + log(P(cat|<s>, a)) + log(P(sat|a, cat)) +
   log(P(on|cat, sat)) + log(P(the|sat, on)) + log(P(mat|on, the)) + 
   log(P(</s>|the, mat)) + log(P(</s>|mat, </s>))
```

Where `<s>` is used to symbolize the start of the sentence and `</s>` to symbolize the end of the sentence. We are using trigram, therefore it must be two of these two symbols at the start of the sentence and at the end.

And the probability of any of the above trigrams can be calculated like so:

```
P(w3|w1, w2) = count(w1, w2, w3) / count(w2 w3)
```

You can get back to these two videos by Prof. Danial Jurafsky (Stanford) if you need more understanding:

- n-grams: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Saq1QagC8KY
- estimating n-grams: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=paCMAZ-lKq8